# Synchronizing Threads in Java using monitor class

Tags: java, multithreading

The following program creates threads that generate random numbers.

How do I **change the `Monitor` class** so it will control the threads in a way that the print outs will be printed by the order of each Thread's ID?

Solutions like "invoke `run` method instead of `start`" are not accepted.

The given classed are:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Monitor mon = new Monitor();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            new T(i, mon).start();

        System.out.println("Finished");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Monitor {

    public void print(int id, int num) {
        System.out.println("id=" + id + " num=" + num);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class T extends Thread {
    private int id;
    private Monitor mon;

    public T(int i, Monitor m) {
        id = i;
        mon = m;
    }

    private int calc() {
        int num = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            num = num + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        return num;
    }

    public void run() {
        int num = calc();
        mon.print(id, num);
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, but I think it's interesting mainly because of the restriction that only `Monitor` can be changed. Making it synchronized or apply any other sort of locking is probably more likely to print the thread IDs in order, but it's not guaranteeing it.

Comment: "_Solutions like "invoke run method instead of start" are not accepted._" That just really makes me want to donate my time to you.

Comment: The idea is that Monitor will contain all what calculate until now and in every time that the function print call it print all the ready calculation in the id order..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need the thread trying to print to wait and block until its ID is the expected ID:

```
public class Monitor {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private int expectedId = 0;

    public void print(int id, int num) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (id != expectedId) {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("id=" + id + " num=" + num);
            expectedId++;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I came to a solution without lock (see my answer). Am I missing something? Any benefits to it?

Comment: You're just using `this` as a lock instead of using a dedicated object. That doesn't change much... except that there is no way in my solution that some other code also uses my lock to synchronize a totally different thing. I also don't understand the point of the THREADS_NUM constant, especially considering that you set it to 10 although you have 20 threads.

Comment: Thanks, you made me understand a few things more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

For the strange task only strange solution can be proposed. My version would be like this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Monitor {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

    public synchronized void print(int id, int num) {
        map.put(id, num);
        if(map.size() == 20) {
            for(Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet())
            System.out.println("id=" + entry.getKey() + " num=" + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

It solves your problem. Objections like "it depends on number of threads" are not accepted.

Comment: Cheater! :-) I must admit this is the first solution I had in mind too.

Comment: @JBNizet, your version is much better though, voteup :-)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @JBNizet's answer I came to this solution (using `this` as lock):

```
public class Monitor {
    private int currId = 0;

    public synchronized void print(int id, int num) {
        while (id != currId) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("id=" + id + " num=" + num);
        currId++;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```